# Standardize data in cross validation

Tags: python, cross-validation

should it be advisable to standardize/scale the data on each subset of cross validation, or would it be enough to do it once with the full set?

My question is related to the fact of including or not the scaling phase in a pipeline

This:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

scaler = StandardScaler()
algorithm = LogisticRegression(random_state=42)
pipe = make_pipeline(scaler, algorithm)

kfold = KFold(10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
results = cross_val_score(pipe, features, target, cv=kfold )
```

Versus this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
features_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(features)
model = LogisticRegression(random_state=42)

kfold = KFold(10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
results = cross_val_score(model, features_scaled, target, cv=kfold )
```

I don't include the data, as I think is not necessary to reproduce. If there are many CV iterations (like in LOO) or the dataset is really big, wouldn't it be a waste of time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you standardize the data on the full set and then perform cross-validation, then you are effectively leaking information from the validation set into the training set. This can lead to overfitting and overly optimistic performance. I recommend scaling each fold of the cross-validation so that scaling is not applied to the validation data.

Comment: To do this safety-first approach, I would have thought that for each fold you need to scale (and relocate) on the training set minus the cross-validation fold and then apply that scaling (and relocation) to the cross-validation fold.  Once you have chosen your final model and tuned your hyperparameters, you would then scale (and relocate) on the full training set (excluding the test set), train your model, and apply that final scaling (and relocation) to the test set.

Comment: Thanks both of you!